# Google app scripts not replacing all text in a slide

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-apps-script, google-slides-api

I have a map of slide numbers with an array of associated variables.

```
const slidesMap = {
  0: ['firstName', 'date'],
  10: ['diversityScore', 'diversityDef', 'butyrateEfficiency', 'propionateEfficiency'],
  15: ['bacteria_1_three', 'bacteria_1_three_def', 'bacteria_2_three', 'bacteria_2_three_def', 'bacteria_3_three', 'bacteria_3_three_def'],
  16: ['bacteria_1', 'bacteria_1_def', 'bacteria_2', 'bacteria_2_def', 'bacteria_3', 'bacteria_3_def'],
  18: ['bacteria_10', 'bacteria_10_def', 'bacteria_11', 'bacteria_11_def', 'bacteria_12', 'bacteria_12_def', 'bacteria_13', 'bacteria_13_def','bacteria_14', 'bacteria_14_def', 'bacteria_15', 'bacteria_15_def'],
};
```

I have a map of variables generated from a spreadsheet,

```
const variablesMap = new Map();
 const generalValues = sheet.getRange('A1:B47').getValues();

  generalValues.forEach(row => {
    variablesMap.set(row[0], row[1]);
  });
```

Then I populate the necessary slides with necessary variables.

```
for (const page in slidesMap) {
    const variables = slidesMap[page];

    let newSlide = slides[page];

    let shapes = newSlide.getShapes();
    shapes.forEach(shape => {
      variables.forEach(variable => {
        shape.getText().replaceAllText(`{{${variable}}}`,variablesMap.get(variable), true);
      });
    }); 
  }
```

When I log the variables in the loop, I have everything I need both in variablesMap and in slides map. Also the page numbers are correct.

What I get, is half populated slides. For example on slide 15 4/6 variables are populated. {{bacteria_1_three_def}} and {{bacteria_3_three}} are still as placeholders.

What am I missing?

On slide 18 it's even worse. all the `..._def` are populated, but `bacteria_...` are as placeholders.

I am loosing my head.

I tried logging, everything seems correct.

link to [slides](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1NktACAbR_54XqBoMXJW0YZkZnsp2lVqcYIOO-1TMzc8/edit?usp=sharing)

Solution: As @Tanaike hinted, the problem was in grouped elements. I ungrouped all the elements manually on the slides and the script worked just fine :)

Comment: From your question, I thought that in your question, to know your sample Spreadsheet and sample Slides might help thinking of the solution. So, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet and Slides?

Comment: @Tanaike slides added. Since I have multiple spreadsheets and multiple tables from which I create the variablesMap, I don't think it's very helpful to share the sheets without sharing full code. As I said before, the variablesMap is comprehensive and no variables are missing from it when logging.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your provided Google Slides, I proposed a modification point as an answer. Please confirm it. If that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike I created a spreadsheet link and changed range accordingly :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I saw your provided Google Slides, I noticed that your slides have several groups including shapes. In this case, all placeholders including groups cannot be modified with only `shapes.forEach(shape => {,,,})` in your script. I thought that this might be the reason for your current issue.

In this case, I thought that it is required to check the groups using the script. When your script is modified, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
let newSlide = slides[page];

let shapes = newSlide.getShapes();
shapes.forEach(shape => {
  variables.forEach(variable => {
    shape.getText().replaceAllText(`{{${variable}}}`,variablesMap.get(variable), true);
  });
});
```

#### To:

```
let newSlide = slides[page];

let shapes = newSlide.getShapes();
shapes.forEach(shape => {
  variables.forEach(variable => {
    shape.getText().replaceAllText(`{{${variable}}}`,variablesMap.get(variable), true);
  });
});

// I added below script.
newSlide.getGroups().forEach(g => {
  g.getChildren().forEach(c => {
    if (c.getPageElementType() == SlidesApp.PageElementType.SHAPE) {
      variables.forEach(variable => {
        c.asShape().getText().replaceAllText(`{{${variable}}}`, variablesMap.get(variable), true);
      });
    }
  });
});
```

#### Note:

- In this modification, it supposes that your values of `generalValues` are correct values. Please be careful about this.
- By the way, the keys of `12` and `18` are not included in your `slidesMap`. By this, the placeholders on pages 13 and 17 of Google Slides are not replaced. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [getGroups()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slide#getgroups)
- [getChildren()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/group#getchildren)

Comment: I edited the code with your suggestion, but unfortunately it didn't help. The slides look exactly the same. Keys for 12 and 18 are in the real generalValues object, I have deleted them from this example only. Still lost on what's the problem. You seem to be correct, that the issue is with slides.

Comment: As you have seen I have striped off most of the stuff from slides because of the PI. There are also some charts which are linked to a spreadsheet. Might that affect the outcome too?

Comment: @kaiak Thank you for replying. About `but unfortunately it didn't help. The slides look exactly the same. Keys for 12 and 18 are in the real generalValues object`, I deeply apologize for this. As I have already mentioned in my 1st comment, it is required to know your Google Slides and Google Spreadsheet. Because, when I tested simple sample values and your Slides, no issue occurs. And I confirmed that the values of `slidesMap` could be replaced. And, when I tried to open your provided Spreadsheet, unfortunately, I cannot open it. I apologize for this. Can you confirm it again?

Comment: @kaiak About `There are also some charts which are linked to a spreadsheet.`, in only your showing script, it seems that your script doesn't use the charts. But, from your question, I cannot correctly imagine your current actual situation. So, I cannot know the modification points in your current actual script. I think that this is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for my poor skill again.

Comment: @kaiak Although, unfortunately, I cannot still confirm your provided Spreadsheet, when I tested your new Google Slides using my proposed modified script with a simple value of `generalValues`, no error occurs. I confirmed that the values of `slidesMap` could be correctly used and the placeholders could be replaced. I apologize for this. By the way, if you provide your spreadsheet, please also provide your script for correctly replicating your current issue. By this, I would like to confirm it. If you can cooperate in resolving your issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: @kaiak Unfortunately, I cannot still open your provided Spreadsheet. So, I would like to propose a simple sample value of `generalValues`. Please set the following script instead of `const generalValues = sheet.getRange('A1:B47').getValues();`. And, test it again. When I tested my proposed modified script using this sample value, the placeholders of the pages of keys in `slidesMap` could be replaced. Please test it.

Comment: @kaiak `const v1 = [["firstName","sample1"],["date","sample2"],["diversityScore","sample3"],["diversityDef","sample4"],["butyrateEfficiency","sample5"],["propionateEfficiency","sample6"],["bacteria_1_three","sample7"],["bacteria_1_three_def","sample8"],["bacteria_2_three","sample9"],["bacteria_2_three_def","sample10"],["bacteria_3_three","sample11"],["bacteria_3_three_def","sample12"],["bacteria_1","sample13"]];`

Comment: @kaiak `const v2 = [["bacteria_1_def","sample14"],["bacteria_2","sample15"],["bacteria_2_def","sample16"],["bacteria_3","sample17"],["bacteria_3_def","sample18"],["bacteria_10","sample19"],["bacteria_10_def","sample20"],["bacteria_11","sample21"],["bacteria_11_def","sample22"],["bacteria_12","sample23"],["bacteria_12_def","sample24"],["bacteria_13","sample25"],["bacteria_13_def","sample26"],["bacteria_14","sample27"],["bacteria_14_def","sample28"],["bacteria_15","sample29"],["bacteria_15_def","sample30"]];`

Comment: @kaiak `const generalValues = [...v1, ...v2];`

Comment: @kaiak Please test my proposed modified script using my proposed simple value. And, please tell me the result of it.

Comment: I ungrouped the groups on the slides manually and ran my original script. Everything works now! You were correct, the problem was with groups. Thank you very much!